# How to remove duplicated objects from NSArray?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have NSArray() which is include names but there's duplicated names how can i remove them ?

After parse query adding the objects to the NSArray and its duplicated

```
var names = NSArray()
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
        query.whereKey("receivers", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                self.names = objects!
                let set = NSSet(array: self.names as [AnyObject])

                print(objects!.count)
                // count is 4
                // database looks like this (justin , kevin , kevin , joe)
```

Comment: How `test` class looks like? What fields it has?

Comment: @JohnTracid There's many columns but i just want "sender" column which include names, there's names be duplicated, I want to search for all names but skip duplicated, Here's a picture: http://cut.by/QQVnt  See the name1 is duplicated

Comment: check my update. It is just a sample so you need to adopt it for your case.

Comment: @JohnTracid i'm using xcode7 and i got error : Use of undeclared type 'Test' , I've tried test and Test , What's wrong ?

Comment: As I told you early you need to provide your Parse `test` class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your names are strings you could create `NSSet` from array and it will have only different names.

```
let names = ["John", "Marry", "Bill", "John"]
println(names)

let set = NSSet(array: names)
println(set.allObjects)
```

prints:

```
"[John, Marry, Bill, John]"
"[Bill, John, Marry]"
```

Update #1
With new information in question (code fragment) it may look like this

```
var set = Set<String>()
for test in objects as [Test] {
    set.insert(test.sender)
}
self.names = Array(set)
```

Comment: i'm getting error , NSArray is not implicitly convertible to [Anyobject]

Comment: @Salah I had to do `let set = NSSet(array: names as [AnyObject])` when I tried.  Does that help your error?

Comment: @kelan thanks but still count 4 , 2 different names and 2 duplicated in rows.

Comment: @Salah Just to double check: In your original pastebin, you were doing `print(objects!.count)`, which is the original array, not the filtered one.  Are you sure you're checking the filtered one now (which is `self.names` in my pastebin)?

Comment: @Kelan Yes i did, and the app not working well , I just need to take down names rows in parse database without duplicate, Could you help me please?

Comment: @Salah Can you check what type of items are actually in the array.  I've never used the Parse SDK, but maybe they're not actually NSString objects, so they don't hash to be equal.  Can you do `print("type=\(objects!.firstObject!.dynamicType)")` and see what class name it prints out.

Comment: @Kelan, i'm getting error Anyobject doesn't have member firstObject , I've changed to " print(self.name.firstObject!.dynamicType) " I got "PFObject" output

Comment: @Salah Ok, so I think the `PFObject` doesn't have the `-hash` and `-isEqual:` implementations that de-duplicate as you expect here.  I think probably the proper solution to your problem is to tweak your query so that you only get back the results that you want.  But I'm not familiar with the Parse API to help with that.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on John's answer, an NSSet will, by definition, only contain a single copy of each object that hashes to be equal.  So, a common pattern is to convert the array to a set and back.

This will work for any object type that has a reasonable implementation of `-hash` and `-isEqual:`.  As John shows, String is one such object.

You could also do it with pure Swift:

```
let arrayWithDuplicates = [ "x", "y", "x", "x" ]
let arrayWithUniques = Array(Set(arrayWithDuplicates))  // => [ "y", "x" ]
```

But, it looks like you're already working with `NSArray`, so I think the John's example is more applicable.

Also, as my example shows, be aware that the order of the final array is not guaranteed to be in the same order as your original.  If you want that, I think you can use `NSOrderedSet` instead of `NSSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complicated way to approach this that works. You could just run through a loop of the array and create a new one from the original. For example:

```
var check = 0

let originalArray:NSMutableArray = ["x", "y", "x", "z", "y", "z"]
let newArray: NSMutableArray = []
println(originalArray)

for var int = 0; int<originalArray.count; ++int{
    let itemToBeAdded: AnyObject = originalArray.objectAtIndex(int)
    for var int = 0; int<newArray.count; ++int{

        if (newArray == ""){
            break;

        }
        else if ((newArray.objectAtIndex(int) as! String) != itemToBeAdded as! String){

        }
        else if ((newArray.objectAtIndex(int) as! String) == itemToBeAdded as! String){
             check = 1
            break
        }


    }
    if (check == 0){
        newArray.addObject(itemToBeAdded)
    }
}
```

Basically I set a check var = 0. for every object in the originalArray, it loops through the newArray to see if it already exists and if it does the check var gets set to 1 and the object does not get added twice.

Comment: Thank you, Is there anyway to make the parse query not duplicate names ?